# My program wont run, any ideas?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, jlist

I'm doing an assignment at school. I'm supposed to make a program where you can add the name of a product and a score to a list after a product test.

My problem is that i can't run my program and I don't know why. 
Anyone who knows what I have done wrong?

```
package oblig9;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Oblig9 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    DefaultListModel<Oblig9Brus> brus = new DefaultListModel<Oblig9Brus>();

    public Oblig9(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        this.setLayout(fl);

        JList liste = new JList(brus);
        this.add(liste);

        JButton leggTil = new JButton("Legg til brus");
        this.add(leggTil);
        leggTil.addActionListener(this);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String produsent = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Hvilken produsent har du testet?");
        String scoreTekst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Hvilken score vil du gi produket?");
        int score = Integer.parseInt(scoreTekst);

        Oblig9Brus o9b = new Oblig9Brus();
        o9b.setProdusent(produsent);
        o9b.setScore(score);
        brus.addElement(o9b);
    }

}
```

Also have a class for saving the scores

```
package oblig9;

public class Oblig9Brus {
    private String produsent;
    private int score;

    public String getProdusent() {
        return produsent;
    }
    public void setProdusent(String produsent) {
        this.produsent = produsent;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return produsent + " " + score; 
    }
}
```

Comment: any errormessage available???

Comment: What do you mean you "can't run it"?

Comment: Adding a `main` method may help.

Comment: How are you trying to run it and what is happening? Do you get any error messages or exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new Oblig9();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fabian may have the right idea, if you are trying to run it standalone.  I did wrap it in a quick JUnit and this seems to pass fine, but I'm not sure what the error is, if there is one:

```
@Test
public void testIt(){
    Oblig9 instance = new Oblig9();
    assertNotNull(instance);
}
```